# ie-8 getting black outlines on images

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

i am developing a site and getting black outline in ie8
its looking great in all other major browser but not in ie-8
please help me this is my live  link 
http://www.cadellfoods.com.au/food-service-products.html
(the section in circular shape)

please help me 
the code for all images is as following

```
#Section1
{
    background:transparent url('Images/Chilled.png') no-repeat;
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    border:none; outline:none; outline:0;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Comment: It seems good to me in IE8 mode. Can you please post the image? (tag the image link here)

Comment: Never heard of an outline default on any browser.

Comment: At least in IE9 (in IE8 mode) I don't see any outlines. However the background of the page is gray (instead white in IE9 mode) and for a second during page load all the images are visible overlapping each other.

Answer (score 0):

Seems OK in IE 8 too here. maybe you have issues in IE 8 on windows XP

as a good practice, you should not start your ID's or classes with capital letters.

Comment: agree on the capital letters. Use camel case. Like this #section1 and like this #sectionHeader.

Comment: Actually we follow this pattern and when we write name of method in c# then we follow camel case

Answer (score 0):

Might not be it, but I have noticed IE puts borders on *linked* images. You need to undo those defaults.

```
#Section1 a:link img {
   border:none;
}
```

Don't forget the :hover and :visited pseudos.

Just in case try these too

```
#Section1 img {
   border:none;
}
#Section1 a:link {
   border:none;
}
```

Comment: `#Section1 img a:link` makes no sense. That selects a link inside an image, which isn't possible. You mean `#Section1 a:link img`